# Can I get Java Class name in soap handler?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soap-client

I am using JAX-WS web service. I have generated java files using wsimport. The web service which I am working is secured and it will accept only when the soap message is according to the xsd defined.

Now my problem is I have to send a request to the web service using one of the class generated using wsimport. Based on the response I have to send one more request to the web service and so on.My client class have to handle 4 requests and responses. I have 4 java classes for 4 requests.Soap header for all the requests is same but body is different for each requst.

So I wrote an handler which extends SoapHandler class and inject header information to every out going request.Now how to change the Saop body for each request based on the java class.

Can I get Java class name in the handler and build soap body based on the java class? or Please suggest any other approach?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try to format your question in a readable format.

Comment: You should not have to build the SOAP body. JAX-WS does that for you according to the schema used to generate the java classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem using following code

In my handler class

```
public boolean handleMessage(SoapMessageContext context){
......
......
SOAPBody soapbody=context.getMessage().getSOAPBody();

    Iterator itr=soapbody.getChildElements();

    while(itr.hasNext()){


    SOAPElement se=(SOAPElement)itr.next();


    System.out.println("Requsted class name "+se.getElementName().getLocalName());

    }
....

// proces the handler based on your class name

}
```